# Handler for change of value using SliderBar in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using the [SliderBar](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/SliderBar) from the GWT Incubator in one of my current projects.

I want to add a handler which fires whenever the value of the slider changes, but I'm not sure which handler I need to add to get this to work, or whether I need to write one of my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SliderBar`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#kxqvj77bOTo/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/SliderBar.java&q=SliderBar%20package:http://google-web-toolkit-incubator%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) has a method `addChangeListener()` which takes a [`ChangeListener`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ChangeListener.html) whose `onChange()` method will be called when the slider is moved.

It's worth mentioning that `ChangeListener` has been deprecated since GWT 1.6 (as have all *Listeners), so `SliderBar` should probably be updated to use the "new hotness" [`ChangeHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ChangeHandler.html), but adding a ChangeListener will still work in the meantime.

Comment: I must have missed that as it was deprecated. 
It actually did a better job than I expected as it is called at every value the slider passes, not just the one it stops at (which is ideal for what I'm after doing). Thanks